# Ударение в слове "крадущийся"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как правильно ставить ударение в слове "крадущийся"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я обнаружила вот [**такую информацию**](https://www.ekburg.ru/news/18/46904-kak-pravilno-kradushchiysya-ili-kradushchiysya/).

Словари дают разные варианты ударения.
К примеру, «Русский орфографический словарь» Российской академии наук под редакцией В. В. Лопатина указывает, что ударение падает на второй слог — [крадУщийся](https://lopatin.academic.ru/56068/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F).
В то же время словарь «Русское словесное ударение» М. В. Зарвы настаивает на варианте крАдущийся с пояснением: от крАсться.

Орфографический словарь под ред. С. И. Ожегова и А. Б. Шапиро (печатный вариант, 110 тысяч слов, 1957): **крАдущийся**, -аяся, -ееся.

[Орфоэпический словарь русского языка](http://dazor.narod.ru/russkie/slovari/krukover/krukover-all.htm) (В. Круковер): **крАдущийся**.

Комментируя подобные разночтения, справочно-информационный портал «Русский язык» отмечает: «Если в словарях представлены разные варианты, то это свидетельствует о том, что объективно в языке существует колебание нормы, ударение не устоялось».
В данном случае ударение на **А** поддерживается инфинитивом *красть, крАсться* и деепричастием *крАдучись*. Аргумент за ударение на **У** — неудобство произнесение варианта крАдущийся с тремя заударными слогами.

[Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83&start=30) (вопрос №257036) пишет: выбор за Вами, рекомендациям какого словаря следовать.
Таким образом, крАдущийся и крадУщийся — равноправные варианты.

Если бы мне пришлось выбирать, я бы остановилась на втором варианте — краду́щийся.

**P. S.** Интересную статистику дает Е. В. Маринова и В. Н. Немченко ([Частотный словарь акцентных вариантов русского слова](http://www.lib.unn.ru/students/src/Marinova.pdf)). Количественная характеристика: крАдущийся — 7, крадУщийся — 3.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Думал вчера, что выбрал ответ Александра (с телефона как-то все криво). Но Ваш мне тоже очень нравится. :)

Comment: Благодарю. Меня больше всего удивила обнаруженная статистика — мне казалось, что должно было быть наоборот. Ан нет. P. S. Что-то Вас долго не было.

Comment: Да, статистика удивляет, но и радует меня. Почему-то с ударением на А мне кажется красивее. :)) Да как-то повода не было зайти.) Пробудешь какое-то время на сайте, потом ничего нового не приходит и перестаёшь заходить, пока не задашься новым каким-то вопросом.

Answer (score 2):

А я думаю, что верна одна форма: крадУщийся. Она указана у Зализняка и в словаре РАН, ею и надо пользоваться.

У этого глагола такая история. Раньше ударение  в личных формах падало на первый слог, поэтому оно сохранялось и на первом слоге  причастия: крАдутся - крАдущийся. Например у Гумилева: из пещеры крАдется гиена, у Пастернака - крАдущейся росомахой.

Потом это ударение в личных формах устарело, а в причастии еще долго сохранялось, считалось исключением. А потом за несколько лет всё исправили (где-то с 2003 по 2009 год, если судить по одному и тому же словарю в разных изданиях).

Исключение отменили, для причастия действует общее правило (соответствие ударения в личной форме и причастии на УЩ/ЮЩ): поЮт - поЮщий, пИшут - пИшущий, крадУтся - крадУщийся.

А статистика со временем исправится, когда современные словари начнут читать.

Что касается "крАдучись", то здесь во всех случаях ударение падает на гласную перед суффиксом, так что это не поддержка (крАдучись, умЕючи, игрАючи).

Comment: У Пастернака та же россомаха скорее "крадУщаяся":Все обледенело с размаху
В папахе до самых бровей
И крадущейся росомахой
Подсматривает с ветвей.

Comment: Да, это Пастернак, а не Гумилев. Но это пример из словаря, а там ударение поставлено:  крАдущейся.

Comment: Видимо, у составителей словарей своё ощущение ритма строки :)

Comment: Там какой-то сложный ритм, но мне кажется ритмическую паузу (цезуру) удобнее сделать так: И крАдущейся росомахой /Подсматривает с ветвей.

Comment: О своём предпочтении я сказал, но вот источник, в котором этот фрагмент предлагается в качестве теста на ударение (самоочевидного - ответов там не даётся) - вы не поверите тому, как он называется! Приемы развития выразительности чтения **третьеклассников** в процессе изучения лирических стихотворений о природе (c.112-113) https://orcacenter.ru/doc/mr.2018.04.02.pdf

Comment: Да, впечатляет. Но вы думаете, что третьеклассники действительно могут  понять  и выразительно прочитать это стихотворение Пастернака?

Comment: Спасибо! Верно оно ли или нет, в любом случае интересно новое мнение.

Comment: Пожалуй, выделю Ваш ответ. История изменения нормы интересна и многое проясняет. До этого у меня наибольшее недоумение вызвал старый справочник для работников телевидения и радиовещания, написанный с участием Розенталя (когда-то за тележурналистами - тогда это были просто "дикторы" - и напрямую присматривали филологи, оберегая язык от безобразий) - там тоже ударение было на первом слоге.

Answer (score 0):

Ударение на "у".
Никогда не слышал иначе, но на всякий случай проверил по двум словарям: А. Зализняка и Т.Ф. Ивановой. Всё верно.

Comment: Спасибо!*******

Answer (score 0):

Ударение на **втором** слоге, в отличие от слова "крадучись" (на первом). Можно посмотреть в словаре Лопатина на стр. 1009:

https://sheba.spb.ru/lit/lopatin.pdf

**P.S.** Разночтения могут быть связаны с контекстом употребления слова, на который опираются составители словарей (обычно приводится один вариант). Опора на ударение в слове "**крАдучись**" уместна для обоснования произношения связанного с этим словом *прилагательного*: "**крАдущаяся походка**" (как? - **крАдучись = крАдущейся походкой**). Что касается *причастия*, то убедительнее выглядит наследование *глагольного* ударения на втором слоге: **крадУщийся = тот, кто крадётся** (ср. браться-берущийся-берётся). Различие смыслов слова в этих двух вариантах очевидно: походка не может "*красться*", поэтому есть основание к тому, чтобы слова чем-то различались.

На реальную практику произношения (с возможными колебаниями во времени и пространстве) нормативная орфоэпия опирается далеко не всегда. Например, некоторые экспериментальные исследования (Е. Маркланд-Шарапова, 2000) показывают, что ударение в слове **началсЯ**, по поводу которого в словарях **нет** разночтений (хотя в статьях можно встретить ссылку на тенденцию к смещению ударения), *отвергается* большинством носителей языка (на этот предмет тестировались 106 жителей Москвы).

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: Два варианта (для прилагательного и причастия),  но  не знаю, насколько  авторитетен источник. https://где-ударение.рф/в-слове-крадущийся/

Comment: Я пока не видел ни одного такого источника, но раз единомышленники существуют, то в этом что-то есть. Спасибо за ссылку.